# FileDownload using JQuery

Tags: jquery, tomcat

```js
$(document).on("click", "a.fileDownloadLink", function(e) {
  alert("hello file");
  //e.preventDefault();
  //$.fileDownload("D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.76/webapps/sav/WEB-INF/classes/ConfigDataTable.csv");
  $.fileDownload("https://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/FileDownload/DownloadReport/2");
});
```

The above code able to download file from URL?  How i can download a file in my local system?

```
$.fileDownload("D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.76/webapps/sav/WEB-INF/classes/ConfigDataTable.csv");
```

if i tries this it does not work..

How to convert the path of the local file to url so that i can download the same file  when user clicks the link ? I am running this using tomcat server, HTML,Jquery

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There is no way JavaScript can access the file system. The only way to access a file is using filereader which allows JavaScript to read the file. Another way is to hit an endpoint and write some server side code which will return the file data. This is not possible with JavaScript alone.

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful to you

```js
$(function(){
   $(".fileDownloadLin").click(function(){
     $.fileDownload("https://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/FileDownload/DownloadReport/2");
   });         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.fileDownload/1.4.2/jquery.fileDownload.js"></script>

<a class="fileDownloadLin">click here</a>
```

For Example:
    `http://localhost:8080/sav/ConfigDataTable.jsp?fileName=yourfilename`

//file should be in your **resources** folder

```
 try{          
     InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("yourfilename");      response.getOutputStream().flush();
      OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
      while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
         os.write(bytes, 0, read);
      }
      os.flush();
      os.close();
      is.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
      //...
    }
```

or directly you can give your local path

```
try{          
      File f=new File("your path");
      InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
      response.getOutputStream().flush();
      OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
      while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
         os.write(bytes, 0, read);
      }
      os.flush();
      os.close();
      is.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
      //...
    }
```

if you use `http://localhost:8080/sav/ConfigDataTable.jsp?fileName=yourfilename` this URL for **$.fileDownload** it will work.

Comment: i believe the question is how to convert this `D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.76/webapps/sav/WEB-INF/classes/ConfigDataTable.csv` to `https://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/FileDownload/DownloadReport/2` does this answer this question?

Comment: Yes.. Instead of giving an URL?  how i can give my local file path so that it will get downloaded ? or how to convert my local file path to the URL?   The above code also not working for me

Comment: @SathyaVantheymatharam how you have tried can u able to post that code and above code is a sample